# Angular 2 Input type File, ngOnChanges is not performed

Tags: angular, file, validation, input, ngonchanges

I created a custom component and applied it on

```
<input  [ERR]="' '"  required ngModel name="leaseagreement"  type="file" (change)="onFileChange()">
```

[ERR] is created to show error, but hook event of that component ngOnChanges is not performing on selection of file.
If any way to trigger it, Please share.

```
@Component ({
    selector:'[ERR]',
    template:`<template #validationref>
                    <span class="ERR2">{{error}}</span>
            </template>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            ` 
})
export class ERR implements OnInit {
    @Input() ERR:string;
    @Input() ngModel:string;

    @ViewChild('validationref') validationref;
    public error:string = "";

    ngOnInit() {

          }
    ngOnChanges(args: any[]) {
     // my error plugin code
    }
   }
```